# NServiceBus upgrade 2.5 to 3.2 always reinstalls MSMQ, is there a way to stop this?

Tags: c#, nservicebus

I am currently working on updating our application to use NServiceBus 3.2 rather than the 2.5 we have been using. The problem I have is that when I run the service with the reference to 3.2 it has a problem creating the performance counters, which led me to run the RunMeFirst.bat to create the counters.

Once this is done the service runs as expected, but the problem is that RunMeFirst.bat always reinstalls MSMQ in our environment, which in turn deletes all the queues/messages that exist. This is not really an option for us in a production environment, so could do with a way of installing the performance counters but without having to reinstall MSMQ, is this even possible?

Comment: In a way I have partly solved this. The reason MSMQ was being uninstalled was because we had "MSMQ Active Directory Domain Services Integration" and "Multicasting Support" applied on our installation. Removing these but leaving the MSMQ Server Core meant that running the NServiceBus RunMeFirst.bat did not reinstall, and therefore not delete the queues. The "Multicasting Support" etc could then be applied again afterwards, which I hope will all work, I'll update here incase anyone has the issue.

Comment: NSB won't work with AD-integration turned on since that make the MSMQ adressing work in a different way. Not sure if Multicasting works but I would assume that it will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guideline is to only invoke RunMeFirst.bat on fresh machines to avoid the issue that you mention. That said we're planning to improve our infrastructure installers in this regard:

https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/issues/651